Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IChoiceGroupProps & { children?: any; }' in Fluent Ui choicegroup field
I have recently upgraded my SPFX project to lates 1.20.0 and upgraded a lot of dependencies too but now my code started showing weird problems. like Property 'className' does not exist, property 'id' does not exist, property 'disabled' does not exist. Property 'onClick' on Primary Button does not exist.
Attaching my configuration below
Code :
enter image description here
Package.json
enter image description here
enter image description here
tsconfig:
enter image description here
I tried adding and downgrading the packages but nothing seems to work. This code was working previously successfully but not anymore, looking for someone who can help
